# How to select two columns data from the table?

Tags: jquery, datatable, jquery-plugins, html-table

I am using [DataTable plugin](http://www.datatables.net/).

I would like to select two columns of table and get as an array for further processing.

From $.post() call I get Json in following form:

```
{"sEcho": 26,
 "iTotalRecords": 26,
 "iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
 "aaData": [[ "20090301","60"],
            [ "20090302","253"],
            [ "20090303","108"],
            [ "20090304","166"],
... [snip] ...
            [ "20090327","209"],
            [ "20090328","452"],
            [ "20090329","450"],
            [ "20090330","143"] 
           ],
 "aoColumns": [{"sTitle": "The observed Date"},
               {"sTitle": "number of objects"}
              ]
}
```

then I show the table as:

```
$('#queryTable').dataTable(jsondata);
```

Where

```
<table class="display" id="queryTable"></table>
```

I would like to add click event on column of the table which will return me javascript **Array**.

How to get whole column in the data table?

Comment: please rephrase the question by adding these things. confirm the source of data(ajax, javascript array) and also place sample data if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
    var myTable = $("#queryTable").dataTable(
    {
        "aaData": myData,
        "aoColumns": myColumns
    }
);
myDataArray = myTable.fnGetData();

myColumnArray = []
$("#queryTable thead tr th").click(function()
    {
        var index = $(this).index();
        for (var i = 0; i < myTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal(); i++)
        {
            myColumnArray[i] = myDataArray[i][index];
        }
    }
);
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/srMZR/5/ .  Click on the column headers to get an array of the data for that column.

Comment: Very nice! exactly what I need, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this could help:
http://www.bramstein.com/projects/column/

Answer (score 0):

Well, Adam's answer is what you need (as you've already answered it), but here is a (somewhat more difficult) way of doing it. Since I worked on it for a little while, I'll go ahead and post it. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/bXBhZ/4/

Basically, I just iterated over the table row and then used a child selector :eg() to get column 1 and column 2.

Note, the only reason I do it twice is to make sure it was working (which it does, to see select 25 from the display dropdown and go to page 2).

What you want to see is:

```
$('#queryTable tbody tr').each(function(){
    var date = $(this).children('td:eq(0)').text();
    var obj = $(this).children('td:eq(1)').text();
    ...
});
```

Basically, what I do is copy the table by copying all rows into a JSON array (twice...), and then make another DataTable. I use a pre tag to hold the array text, and use jQuery.parseJSON() to use.

So, if for some reason you want to do it this way, here's an example.

**HTML**

```
<table class="display" id="queryTable"></table>
<table class="display" id="queryTable2"></table>
<br style="clear: both;"/>
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

**Javascript**

```
var jsondata = {"sEcho": 26,
                "iTotalRecords": 26,
                 "iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
                 "aaData": [[ "20090301","60"],
                            [ "20090302","253"],
                            [ "20090303","108"],
                            [ "20090304","166"],
                            [ "20090327","209"],
                            [ "20090328","452"],
                            [ "20090329","450"],
                            [ "20090330","143"]
                           ],
                 "aoColumns": [{"sTitle": "The observed Date"},
                               {"sTitle": "number of objects"}
                              ]
};

$('#queryTable').dataTable(jsondata);

var numrows = 1;

$('#queryTable tbody tr').each(function(){
    var date = $(this).children('td:eq(0)').text();
    var obj = $(this).children('td:eq(1)').text();
    var row = "[\""+date+"\",\""+obj+"\"],\n";
    row =  numrows == 1 ? "["+row : row;
    $('#json').append(row);
    numrows++;
});

numrows = 1;

$('#queryTable tbody tr').each(function(){
    var date = $(this).children('td:eq(0)').text();
    var obj = $(this).children('td:eq(1)').text();
    var comma = $('#queryTable tbody tr').length != numrows ? "," : "]";
    var row = "[\""+date+"\",\""+obj+"\"]"+comma+"\n";
    //row =  numrows == 1 ? "["+row : row;
    $('#json').append(row);
    numrows++;
});

var jsondata2 = jsondata;
jsondata2.aaData = jQuery.parseJSON($('#json').text());

$('#queryTable2').dataTable(jsondata2);
```